# Realm update in a callback

Tags: java, android, realm

Let's consider a Utility class which role is to prefetch Medias for later offline vizualisation.

For now my class is build that way :

```
public class MediaDownloadUtils {

    public interface CallBack {
        void callback(String fileFullPath);
    }

    public static void prefechMedia(final Context ctx, final Media media) {

        Log.i("DWNDEBUG", "prefetching");

        final String mediaId = media.getId();

        downloadMedia(ctx, media, false, new CallBack() {
            @Override
            public void callback(final String fileName) {

                Realm realm = null;
                try {
                    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            Media media2 = realm.where(CourseElement.class).equalTo("childType", CourseElementTypes.MEDIAS.name()).equalTo("id", mediaId).findFirst();
                            media2.setFilePath(fileName);
                        }
                    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Log.i("renaud", "sucess !");
                        }
                    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable error) {
                            Log.i("renaud", "error !");
                        }
                    });

                } finally {
                    if (realm != null) {
                        realm.close();
                    }
                    realm = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void downloadMedia(final Context ctx, final Media media, boolean temp, CallBack cb) {...}

    public static void dwnToFile(final Context ctx, final String link, final String fileName, final boolean temp, final CallBack cb) {...}

}
```

So the question is : where to get Realm? If I pass it as an argument, It seems like I'll have a problem doing my things in the callback, which would be on a different thread.

If I do like I've shown in my sample, I'll have to make the callback thread a looper thread.. which I'm not even sure is possible.

Or should I delegate all this work to the original launcher and directly use   `MediaDownloadUtils.downloadMedia()` dealing with the file path each time..

None of these option seems to be the right one, how should I organize this part of code ?

Thank you for your help

---

Edit : solution

```
public class MediaDownloadUtils {

    public interface CallBack {
        void callback(String fileFullPath);
    }

    public static void prefechMedia(final Context ctx, final Media media, Realm realm) {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        final String mediaId = media.getId();

        downloadMedia(ctx, media, false, new CallBack() {
            @Override
            public void callback(final String fileName) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    final Media media = realm.where(CourseElement.class).equalTo("childType", CourseElementTypes.MEDIAS.name()).equalTo("id", mediaId).findFirst();
                    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {

                            Media media2 = realm.where(CourseElement.class).equalTo("childType", CourseElementTypes.MEDIAS.name()).equalTo("id", mediaId).findFirst();
                            media2.setFilePath(fileName);

                        }
                    });

            }
        });
    }

    public static void downloadMedia(final Context ctx, final Media media, boolean temp, CallBack cb) {...}

    public static void dwnToFile(final Context ctx, final String link, final String fileName, final boolean temp, final CallBack cb) {...}

}
```

Comment: What thread does `CallBack` run on?

Comment: Hi Mr EpicPandaForce, my Callback() run on a different thread. I found a solution using a simple handler that I'm testing right now. I'll post my corrected code if it's all good.

Comment: If it's not on the UI thread, why not use mere `realm.executeTransaction()`, and listen for changes on the UI thread with `RealmChangeListener`?

Comment: My problem is where to launch this `realm.executeTraction()`. I don't have to listen the changes. I want to add an attribute to a realm in the callback.

Comment: I added the solution. Would you have improvments to share ?